# customize radio box like in my concept

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is the best way to customize a radio box like this. It should be for ie10, chrome, firefox.
I cant make everything by by own with css and javascript. is there a better way ?

**concept:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hide inputs, and style labels:

```
input[type='checkbox']{
  display: none;
}

label{
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 36px;
}

label::before{
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  content: '';
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #999;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
}

input:checked + label::before{
  background: #ccc;
}
```

[DEMO](http://dabblet.com/gist/5558503)

Comment: nice answer ! is it possible with radio buttons, too ?

Comment: Fixed size somehow possible ?

Comment: Sure, just put a width and `display: inline-block;` on the label

Answer (score 1):

I recently tried something like this and the following tutorials helped me
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/custom-radio-buttons/
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-checkbox-radio/

In my case I used the background-image solution